# API Call works in local but not in live

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, mariadb

I have a custom built API in PHP, that is a simple GET request to a MariaDB database, for a list of records in the database, returned in JSON.

Folder Structure is

```
/api
/api/some/read.php
/api/some/read2.php
/config
/config/Database.php
/models
/models/call.php
/models/call2.php
```

read.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include_once '../../config/Database.php';
include_once '../../models/call.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

$post =  new Call($db);

$result = $post->read();

$num = $result->rowCount();

 if ($num > 0) {
    $post_arr = array();
    $post_arr['data'] = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);

    $post_item = array(

    'id' => $id,
    'title' => $title,
    'category' => $category,
    'address' => $address,
    'website' => $website,
    'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
    'placeUrl' => $placeUrl,
    'info' => $info,
       );
   array_push($post_arr['data'], $post_item);
 }
        echo json_encode($post_arr);
} else {
  echo json_encode(
    array('message' => 'No info Found')
  );
 }
```

here's read2.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include_once '../../config/Database.php';
include_once '../../models/call2.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

$post =  new Call($db);

$result = $post->read();

$num = $result->rowCount();
 if ($num > 0) {

    $post_arr = array();
    $post_arr['data'] = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);

    $post_item = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'title' => $title,
    'category' => $category,
    'address' => $address,
    'website' => $website,
    'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
    'placeUrl' => $placeUrl,
    'info' => $info,
       );
   array_push($post_arr['data'], $post_item);
 }
    echo json_encode($post_arr);
} else {
  echo json_encode(
    array('message' => 'No info Found')
  );
 }
```

then there's Database.php

```
<?php

  class Database {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = 'data';
    private $username = '01';
    private $password = '01!';
    private $conn;

    public function connect() {
      $this->conn = null;

      try {
        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$this->host . ';dbname=' .$this->db_name,
        $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }

      return $this->conn;
    }
  }
```

call.php

```
<?php
  class Call {
    
    private $conn;
    private $table = 'tester';

    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $client_name;
    public $category;
    public $address;
    public $website;
    public $phoneNumber;
    public $placeUrl;
    public $info;

    public function __construct($db) {
      $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function read() {

      $query = 'SELECT
           id,
           title,
           category,
           address,
           website,
           phoneNumber,
           placeUrl,
           info
        FROM
            ' .$this->table. '
        ORDER BY
            id DESC';

  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

  $stmt->execute();

  return $stmt;
    }
  }
```

call2.php

```
<?php
  class Call {
    
    private $conn;
    private $table = 'test';

    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $client_name;
    public $category;
    public $address;
    public $website;
    public $phoneNumber;
    public $placeUrl;
    public $info;

    public function __construct($db) {
      $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function read() {

      $query = 'SELECT
           id,
           title,
           category,
           address,
           website,
           phoneNumber,
           placeUrl,
           info
        FROM
            ' .$this->table. '
        ORDER BY
            id DESC';

  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

  $stmt->execute();

  return $stmt;
    }
  }
```

database is structured as follows

```
data
-test
-tester
```

Now here's the weird part:
I have Postman and Xampp installed on local machine. when i go to mysite.com/api/some/read2.php, i get the following json return:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": "115",
            "title": "graphers",
            "category": "service",
            "address": "",
            "website": ".com",
            "phoneNumber": "+1 number",
            "placeUrl": "https://**",
            "info": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "114",
            "title": "place name",
            "category": "categoryname",
            "address": "the address",
            "website": ".com",
            "phoneNumber": "+1 ",
            "placeUrl": "https://**",
            "info": ""
        },
etc.
```

I didn't think it necessary to post the full 115 records it returned, I'm sure you peeps understand what Im getting at.

when I go to mysite.com/api/some/read.php I get absolutely nothin even though there are 384 records to return.
Oh yeah, the weird part:
I compressed the "api" folder to zip and exported the "data" db (structure and data) to .sql
Then I did a fresh install of xampp and postman and got everything configured, went into phpMyAdmin and imported the .sql file to a new database.  unzipped 'api' folder into localhost on my machine.

localhost/api/some/read.php returns:

```
{"data":[{"id":"384","title":
```

for all 384 records....

I changed nothing other than the username and password for the local machine MariaDB setup.
Am I missing something? Obviously.

Things I have tried:

1. I added the following to the end of read.php and got a return of all 384 records I want in the call.json file.

```
$req_dump = print_r( $post_arr, true );

$fp = file_put_contents( 'call.json', $req_dump );
```

1. I created an entirely new database and changed the names of the tables and database, and created a new user with full privileges, and the same thing happens-works locally, read.php returns a 200 result but no data.
2. Deleting ALL db info and all users on my site (backed up first of course I'm not THAT crazy, and there were only 35/48 no big deal.) Updating PHP/Apache/MariaDB on my site, purging cachewall, making a new unsecured website on a free hosting system, with the same information: in between each step, i created new dbs and new php files and same thing over and over and over again. Regardless of LITERALLY Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V read2.php and call2.php, to read.php and call.php, changing the table name, and the inclusion in read.php to models/call.php....nothing works....if I change it to call2.php, read.php returns the data from test, if I change

```
private $table = "test";
```

to

```
private $table = "tester";
```

I get no data. with 'test' i get data.  The table column names are exactly the same, in the exact same order, named the exact same things, and filled with variations of the same type of info for each line.

I don't get it.  I'm over explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix.
in Database.php I changed:

```
$this->username, $this->password);
```

to

```
$this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Somewhere in the data for $post_arr there are some characters that don't get along with json_encode.  After a fair amount of debugging, I finally figured out that it was returning this error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON inputstatus: -1


Resource settings for Get collection (GET)
-------------------
Resource URL: https://eaxmple.com/api/post/
Relative path: read.php
```

So then I changed this in read.php/read2.php

```
echo json_encode($post_arr);
```

to

```
  echo json_encode($post_arr);
    $req = json_encode($post_arr);
   $fp = file_put_contents("req2.json", $req);
```